# How should I handle character encoding when cross-compiling from Linux to Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, mingw, cross-compiling

How should I handle character encoding/conversion issues when cross-compiling from Linux to Windows using mingw?

---

I am attempting to cross-compile a Qt project on a Linux system for a Windows target. I've installed (what I believe to be) all the required mingw packages, and I think my environment is configured correctly. However, when I try to configure the Qt libraries, it fails when trying to compile `project.cpp`:

```
project.cpp: In member function 'QStringList& QMakeProject::values(const QString&, QMap<QString, QStringList>&)':
project.cpp:3062:51: error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' for argument '1' to 'WINBOOL GetComputerNameA(LPSTR, LPDWORD)'
gmake: *** [project.o] Error 1
```

I was able to hack around this single error by replacing `wchar_t*` with `LPSTR` in the code, but then I just ran into another error. It seems obvious that I am now facing a character encoding problem. I'm imagining that there might be some compiler options that would handle the conversion properly (I was looking at `fexec-charset`), but I'm not even really sure about the problem. I understand that `LPSTR` and the like are Microsoft typedefs,  but how should mingw handle them when cross-compiling from Linux for a Windows target?

Thanks!

---

Here is the offending lines of code from qmake/project.cpp:

```
DWORD name_length = 1024;
wchar_t name[1024];
if (GetComputerName(name, &name_length))
    ret = QString::fromWCharArray(name);
```

It seems `GetComputerName` is a macro which is being expanded to `GetComputerNameA`, when apparently I need `GetComputerNameW`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, almost all Windows API functions (e.g. `GetComputerName`) will resolve to the ANSI implementations (e.g. `GetComputerNameA`) as opposed to their wide char variants (e.g. `GetComputerNameW`).

Try `#define UNICODE` before your `#include <windows.h>` or pass the macro as an argument to your compiler.

For more info, see [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Unicode#Windows_Implementation) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/15/184076.aspx).

Comment: Both worked, but I ended up setting it as a configure option. Now I have a whole slew of other errors, but this one seems to be resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Ilian Pinzon Hi, could you tell where I put the `#define UNICODE`? I'm compiling the(source Qt5.2.1) on windows. I got same error
`project.cpp: In member function 'QStringList& QMakeProject::values(const QString&, QMap<QString, QStringList>&)':`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the wide version of the WINAPI functions : `GetComputerNameA` becomes `GetComputerNameW`, etc.

Unicode versions (aka "wide") are suffixed with a `W` whereas ANSI version are suffixed with a `A`. They respectively accept `LPWSTR` and `LPSTR` as string arguments (LPWSTR being an alias for wchar_t*).

There also are macros which expand into one or the other depending on your unicode configuration. See the documentation of msdn for examples : [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I did read that, but I'm trying to compile the Qt libraries. Why would I need to modify the code? Shouldn't I be able to compile as is? To be clear, I'm compiling Qt's open source libraries - the version packaged for all platforms.

Comment: Yes, it definitively should compile out-of-the-box. However, you are cross-compiling, and the source is probably tailored for a windows mingw install. If that's an option, I would build it using a vanilla windows install under wine.

Answer (score 1):

You misconfigured Qt.

A correctly configured Qt build adds `-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE` (among a lot of other things) which remedies the problem you're experiencing.

Cross-compiling Qt is no fun task, nor is it easy to do correctly.

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed that the qmake.conf I've been using all along included a line: "DEFINES = UNICODE ...". Adding `-DUNICODE` to the configure command line seemed to have no effect. I was able to get it to work by defining `CFLAGS = -DUNICODE`.